# Cant initialise replica set on debian (open/create failed in createPrivateMap)

Tags: mongodb, debian

I try to setup MongoDB on my new virtual Server running with Debian 7.3. If a try to configurate the replica set with

```
hosts = {
   "_id" : "rs0",
   "version" : 1,
   "members" : [
      {
         "_id" : 0,
         "host" : "localhost:27017"
      }
   ]
}

rs.initiate(hosts);
```

MongoDB crashes with following exceptions:

```
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.599 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3616 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=lvps176-28-17-95.dedicated.hosteurope.de
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.599 [initandlisten]
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.600 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ. This is known to be broken!!!
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.600 [initandlisten]
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.600 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.7
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.600 [initandlisten] git version: 0161738abf06c1f067b56a465b706efd6f4bf2aa
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.600 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.600 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.600 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", replSet: "rs0" }
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.609 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.609 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.740 [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster=true 2.38
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.780 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.780 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.786 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
Tue Jan 21 00:10:24.786 [rsStart] replSet info you may need to run replSetInitiate -- rs.initiate() in the shell -- if that is not already done
Tue Jan 21 00:10:27.429 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50602 #1 (1 connection now open)
Tue Jan 21 00:10:34.786 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.160 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate admin command received from client
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.163 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate config object parses ok, 1 members specified
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.164 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate all members seem up
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.164 [conn1] ******
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.164 [conn1] creating replication oplog of size: 24630MB...

Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.165 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.1, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.165 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.205 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.1, size: 2047MB,  took 0.036 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.206 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.2, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.233 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.2, size: 2047MB,  took 0.027 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.234 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.3, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.255 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.3, size: 2047MB,  took 0.02 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.256 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.4, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.275 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.4, size: 2047MB,  took 0.019 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.276 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.5, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.355 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.5, size: 2047MB,  took 0.079 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.356 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.6, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.372 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.6, size: 2047MB,  took 0.014 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.372 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.7, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.498 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.7, size: 2047MB,  took 0.121 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.499 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.8, filling with zeroes...
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.546 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.8, size: 2047MB,  took 0.046 secs
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.546 [conn1] ERROR: mmap private failed with out of memory. (64 bit build)
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.546 [conn1] Assertion: 13636:file /var/lib/mongodb/local.8 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)
0xde0151 0xda188b 0xda1dcc 0xa5a63b 0xa5af9a 0xaba3b1 0x8d518d 0x8d5698 0x8d577f 0x8d5a1e 0xabbb00 0xac1429 0xa75908 0xc10af1 0x8dd4da 0x8de04d 0x8df582 0xa81f00 0xa867cc 0x9fa469
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xde0151]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x9b) [0xda188b]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xda1dcc]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8MongoMMF13finishOpeningEv+0x1fb) [0xa5a63b]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8MongoMMF6createERKSsRyb+0x5a) [0xa5af9a]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13MongoDataFile4openEPKcib+0x141) [0xaba3b1]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database7getFileEiib+0xbd) [0x8d518d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database8addAFileEib+0x38) [0x8d5698]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database12suitableFileEPKcibb+0xaf) [0x8d577f]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database11allocExtentEPKcibb+0x9e) [0x8d5a1e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13_userCreateNSEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjERSsPb+0x7a0) [0xabbb00]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12userCreateNSEPKcNS_7BSONObjERSsbPb+0x2b9) [0xac1429]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11createOplogEv+0xa78) [0xa75908]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18CmdReplSetInitiate3runERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x1da1) [0xc10af1]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x3a) [0x8dd4da]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPS0_RNS_6ClientEiPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x71d) [0x8de04d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x5f2) [0x8df582]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x40) [0xa81f00]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_+0xd7c) [0xa867cc]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x9fa469]
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.563 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate exception: file /var/lib/mongodb/local.8 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)
Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.563 [conn1] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetInitiate: { _id: "rs0", version: 1.0, members: [ { _id: 0.0, host: "localhost:27017" } ] } } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:401$
Tue Jan 21 00:10:44.787 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
Tue Jan 21 00:10:53.835 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate admin command received from client
Tue Jan 21 00:10:53.835 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate config object parses ok, 1 members specified
Tue Jan 21 00:10:53.835 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate all members seem up
Tue Jan 21 00:10:53.835 [conn1] replSet info saving a newer config version to local.system.replset
Tue Jan 21 00:10:54.564 Invalid access at address: 0x18 from thread: conn1

Tue Jan 21 00:10:54.564 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Why MongoDB tries to create 8 files a 2GB? My machine run with 16GB ram, may that is the problem? Because in one line the error "[conn1] ERROR: mmap private failed with out of memory. (64 bit build)" looks like my machine run out of memory. But i only create a replica set with one member and an empty database. Sombody know that bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not RAM but disk space that is the problem, it's not a bug either.

`Tue Jan 21 00:10:40.164 [conn1] creating replication oplog of size: 24630MB...`

From MongoDB docs:

> The oplog (operations log) is a special capped collection that keeps a
>   rolling record of all operations that modify the data stored in your
>   databases. MongoDB applies database operations on the primary and then
>   records the operations on the primary’s oplog. The secondary members
>   then copy and apply these operations in an asynchronous process. All
>   replica set members contain a copy of the oplog, allowing them to
>   maintain the current state of the database.
>
> For 64-bit Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, and Windows systems, MongoDB
>   allocates 5% of the available free disk space to the oplog. If this
>   amount is smaller than a gigabyte, then MongoDB allocates 1 gigabyte
>   of space.

Above via http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/

Oplog is needed for replication (It's a capped collection of a fixed size) and this is created automatically when you create replica set. `oplogSize` can be set via configuration options (if you would like to just experiment with the setup and can't free up some more disk space).
Here's a doc on it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#oplogSize

However:

> Once the mongod has created the oplog for the first time, changing
>   oplogSize will not affect the size of the oplog.

via http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#oplogSize

If you would like to change oplogSize after it has been already created you could use this tutorial: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/

However if this is your "playground" installation, it better to delete content of your old MongoDB data directory (`/var/lib/mongodb`), change config file `/etc/mongodb.conf` (or pass --oplogSize param to mongo when it starts) and just have a "fresh start" with smaller oplog or point your MongoDB `dbpath` directory to a place where it has more disk space.